# When i try to open my app first time it's not showing any value fetched from my sqlite database

Tags: android, sqlite

I am  facing a problem. When I open my app first time it's not showing any value fetched from my sqlite database. When I try again to open the app from my mobile it shows all values. And when I try twice it show all the value twice along with previous values... sorry for my bad English.

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
public class DatabaseAccess {
public static  boolean open =false;
public  static  Bitmap[] theimage =new Bitmap[10];
public static byte[] image;
public  static  int i=0;
public static String name; //for showing data in textview


private SQLiteOpenHelper openHelper;

private SQLiteDatabase database;

private static DatabaseAccess instance;


private DatabaseAccess(Context context){
    this.openHelper =new DatabaseOpenHelper(context);
}

public static DatabaseAccess getInstance(Context context){
    if(instance== null){
        instance=new DatabaseAccess(context);
    }
    return instance;
}

public void open(){
    if(open==false) {
        this.database = openHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        open = true;
    }
    }



public  void close(){
    if(open==true) {
        if (database != null) {
            this.database.close();
        open=false;
        }
    }
}



public  void getdatabase3(){

    Cursor cursor =database.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM cpu ",null);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    while(!cursor.isAfterLast()){
         name=cursor.getString(1); //for Showing In TextBox
        image=cursor.getBlob(2);

        ByteArrayInputStream imagesteam=new ByteArrayInputStream(image);
     theimage[i]  = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(imagesteam);
        cursor.moveToNext(); //for reading next row or line
        i++;
    }
    cursor.close();
}



}

}

public class DatabaseOpenHelper extends SQLiteAssetHelper {

private static final String DATABASE_NAME="computer5.db";

private static final int DATABASE_VERSION=5;

public DatabaseOpenHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null,  DATABASE_VERSION);
}
}


import android.app.Application;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.Switch;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class ScrollingActivity extends AppCompatActivity 
implements   View.OnClickListener {

int cpu_num= DatabaseAccess.i;
ImageButton[] imageButtons =new ImageButton[cpu_num+1];


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


        DatabaseAccess databaseAccess = DatabaseAccess.getInstance(this);


databaseAccess.open();

//  List<String> data1=databaseAccess.getdatabase();
databaseAccess.getdatabase3();


    setContentView(R.layout.activity_scrolling);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);


    LinearLayout 
 linearLayout= (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.liner_tareq1);
    int width= 400;


    ViewGroup.LayoutParams layoutParams=
  new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(width,ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);

    for(int i=1;i<=cpu_num;i++) {
imageButtons[i]=new ImageButton(linearLayout.getContext());
imageButtons[i].setImageBitmap(
DatabaseAccess.theimage[DatabaseAccess.i -    i]);


imageButtons[i].setLayoutParams(layoutParams);

linearLayout.addView(imageButtons[i]);

imageButtons[i].setOnClickListener(this);
}databaseAccess.close();
}




@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_scrolling, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}


@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    for(int i=1;i<=cpu_num;i++) {
        if (v == imageButtons[i]) {
            btntoast(v);

        }
    }
}



public void btntoast(View view) {
    Context context=getApplicationContext();
    LayoutInflater inflater=getLayoutInflater();

    View customToastroot =inflater.inflate(R.layout.toast, null);

    Toast customtoast=new Toast(context);

    customtoast.setView(customToastroot);
    customtoast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL |     Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL,0, 0);
    customtoast.setDuration(Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
    customtoast.show();
}
}
```

Comment: Please ask me for further information..I really need an Answer..

Comment: Hi, is SQLiteAssetHelper a third party library?